# Вернуть индекс и вернуть значение по индексу

Tags: java, массивы

Приветствую. Снова нужна ваша помощь. Пишу своеобразную программу для кодирования.
Есть текст который надо закодировать. Пусть в массиве 
`String[] text = {ace bdf}` есть набор символов для кодировки - final `char[] KEY_WORDS = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}`. Я пробегаю по тексту и ищу совпадения со вторым массивом, и когда нахожу - возвращаю в новосозданый массив индекс совпадения в поле `KEY_WORDS`. То есть у меня получается новый массив `int[]total = {0,2,4,1,3,5}`.
Вот до сюда проблем нет. Теперь надо это раскодировать - взять массив total, и сравнить его с массивом `KEY_WORDS`. Только вот в чем проблема - мне нужно сравнить значение с `total` и индекс в `KEY_WORDS`. Спасибо

```
public static ArrayList arrayCodeNumber(char[] s, char[] ss) {

    ArrayList total = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ss.length; j++) {
            if (s[i] == ss[j]) {
                total.add(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String filename = "C:\\a.java";

    char[] s = read(filename).toCharArray();
    final char[] KEY_WORDS = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '_', '-', ' '};

    ArrayList a = arrayCodeNumber(s, KEY_WORDS);
    System.out.println(a);


    String[] output = new String[a.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i != a.size(); i++) {
        output[i] = (String) a.get(i);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
        if (output[i] == ??? )
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Приложите пример Вашего решения

Comment: Пока админы думают, попрошу Вас оформить Ваш вопрос более читабельным. Для этого необходимо весь Ваш код поместить внутрь специальных символов. При создании(редактировании) вопроса внизу есть подсказки по оформлению. Так Ваш вопрос будет намного более восприимчив. Тем самым Вы быстрее получите на него ответ!

Comment: например, первый символ - `char c = KEY_WORLDS[total[0]);` для получения всей строки пройдите циклом по всему массиву `total`

Comment: простите, спешил очень, сейчас исправлю все

Comment: Я не сильно еще разбираюсь ( И мне не совсем понятно то что вы написали. Там точно все со скобками нормально ?

Comment: ну .. крайняя тоже должна быть прямой, как и остальные :)

Comment: Да, метод "тыка" мне ответил так же )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нельзя написать `String[] text = {ace bdf}`. Надо либо
   `String[] text = {"ace bdf"};`,
   либо
   `String[] text = {"ace", "bdf"};`.
   Первый вариант не выглядит полезным в вашем контексте -- это массив, содержащий только одну строку.
2. Для декодирования вам не надо сравнивать массив `total` с массивом 'KEY_WORDS'. Достаточно использовать индексы, хранящиеся в массиве `total`, для извлечения элементов из массива 'KEY_WORDS', типа такого:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++) 
     System.out.print(KEY_WORDS[total[i]]) //
   ```
3. Необходимо позаботиться о том, чтобы никакой символ во входных данных не мог привести к ошибке. Если для очередного символа из входных данных нет соответствия в массиве 'KEY_WORDS', как поступит ваша программа - какое значение она запишет в `total` и что будет делать, когда встретит это значение при декодировании?
4. В вашем подходе теряется информация о структуре входных данных (разбиении на слова). Если вам нужно эту информацию сохранить, следует либо отмечать конец слова специальным кодом в `total` и соответственно обрабатывать его при декодировании, либо воспринимать входные данные не как массив слов, а как одну строку, содержащую в т.ч. и пробелы, и кодировать/декодировать эти пробелы так же, как и прочие символы.
5. Я бы все кодирование/декодирование вынес в отдельный класс, с таким вот, например, интерфейсом:

   ```
   class Crypto {
     Crypto(Object[][] codeTable) { ... } // Таблица кодировки
     int encrypt(char plain) { .... }     // Возвращает код символа
     char decrypt(int cipher) { .... }    // Возвращает символ по его коду
   }
   ```

   Который можно использовать как-то так:

   ```
   Crypto encryptor = new Crypto({
     {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, // И так далее - таблица кодировки 
   });
   // ... 
   ArrayList<Integer> cryptedData = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)              // str - Исходная строка
     cryptedData.add(encryptor.encrypt(str.charAt(i)));  // шифруем 
   // ... 
   for (Integer cipher: cryptedData)
     System.out.print(encryptor.decrypt(cipher));        // Расшифровываем
   ```

   Это довольно коряво и небрежно, только чтобы продемонстрировать идею, доводите её до ума сами.
   Использование отдельного класса позволит использовать его еще где-то, усовершенствовать алгоритм, не трогая основной программы, и т.д. -- масса преимуществ. Для этого ООП и придумали - пользуйтесь.

Comment: Это написано до того, как топикстартер добавил код в свой вопрос, так что теперь ответ не вполне адекватен вопросу, но уж не буду переписывать. Пусть сам думает, как применить это к своему коду.

Comment: Да, я понимаю что в массиве KEY_WORDS должны быть перечислены все допустимые символы, пример просто надо было быстро настрочить, в среде у меня всех этих мелких недочетов нет. Меня интересует именно декодировка - возврат символа по индексу. Ваш ответ пролил свет, но я просто не знаком с такой вот "штукой", KEY_WORDS[total[i]]. И в дальнейшем я может уйду от чаров к односимвольным стрингам, и в качестве KEY_WORD буду использовать просто какие то тексты, в которых встречаются все допустимые символы. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: @RattenGW, `KEY_WORDS[total[i]]` - это просто извлечение из массива `KEY_WORDS` символа, который находится в позиции, номер которой (т. е. индекс) равен значению i-того элемента массива `total`. Иными словами, `total[i]` - очередной элемент "шифрограммы", а `KEY_WORDS[total[i]]` - соответствующий символ исходного текста.

Comment: Спасибо, запомню эту конструкцию.

Comment: Ребят, как это в ретурн засунуть ? )) Не могу хоть ты тресни...

public char[] textAfterDeCoding(char[] KEY, int[] total) {
        for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
            KEY[total[i]];
        }
    return;
    }

я кажется все перепробовал. И переменную объявлял локальную, но из того что все еще не знаком нормально с этим - KEY[total[i]] кажется весь сырбор. Скажите, а как это называется ? Что б прочесть про это...

Comment: Что засунуть? Но лучше сформулировать проблему толком, с минимальным контекстом, с примером кода, указать, что именно не получается, и оформить как отдельный вопрос.

Comment: `KEY[total[i]]` - это просто обращение к элементу массива. Индексом может быть любое выражение (подходящего типа), в т. ч. элемент другого массива. `a[b[c[d[e[f[g[h[i]]]]]]]]` - тоже может существовать. Почитайте просто какой-нибудь учебник по Java.

Comment: не получается корректно вставить код